# Laravel Migration from 4.2 to 5.1 Errors

Tags: php, laravel-4, laravel-5.1

I'm having a tough time migrating the `Laravel 4.2` files to `Laravel 5.1`. I know it works with a lot of `namespacing`. So probably most of my errors would be because of the `namespace` issues. But I'm a bit new to `namespace` things. So I've some problems. I hope this would also benefit to some other users as well.

`Composer.json` file :

```
   "classmap": [
        "database",
        "app/Http/Controllers",
        "app/Models"
    ],
```

1. According to the Laravel 5.1 updgrade documentation, I've creates a `App\Models` structure for the `Models`.

I'm getting this error related to `Models`. Where `Backers.php` and `User` are the `models`. What `namespace` should I provide to avoid this?

> FatalErrorException in Backers.php line 16: Class 'User' not found

2. I've used `User::find($id)` in some `Views` and `Controllers`. Instead of always calling `\App\User::find($id)`, is there any other way I could approach this problem?
3. `displayLesson` is a `route` name and sometimes I'm getting an error like

> App\Http\Controllers\displayLesson not found.

How can I approach these problems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand ur exact problem but u can write "use ..
 as ..." at the top of the class after namespace the class name you use alot to avoid writing App\User

namespace App\http\superImportantController
Use App\User as User;

Or not a very good practice but time consuming is to add your model into facades in app.php

However , I guess the best practice is to use proper namespacing to be compliant with psr-7

Comment: How do I access a Model function in a view ? (eg: `User::find(1)`)

Comment: you should never use the model function in a view it should be in the controller , and pass it via the data parameter 
In your controller

data = ["user"=>App\User::find(1)];
view::make('viewname',data);

in the view

 {{$user->name}}